# How to do np.dot in specific axis

Tags: numpy

If I have two arrays `a #25x25x3x5` and `b #25x25x5x3`, how can I get dot product of `a` and `b` with the output `25x25x3x3`?

Comment: `a@b` should do it.  Read the `np.matmul` docs for more details.  Basically the 5 is the last axis of `a`, and 2nd to the last for `b`, which is what it expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not the dot product but matrix multiplication.
For two matrices with shapes (A,B) and (B,C) it is defines as:

(A,B) * (B,C) = (A,C)

This corresponds to your last two dimensions and the desired output (3,5)*(5,3)=(3,3).

You can use [`np.matmul`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html#numpy.matmul) like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(25,25,3,5))
b = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(25,25,5,3))

x = np.matmul(a,b)

print(x.shape) # (25, 25, 3, 3)
```

Comment: oh, thanks! so np.dot operating in 2d array is equivalent to np.matmul, right?

Comment: @QiminChen Yes, that's right. For more dimensions, both operate on the last two axes. For dot on other axes, there's also `np.tensordot`.